# Create Jmeter Aggregate report with the thread group name

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I need to create an Aggregate report under a thread group with the thread group name. For Ex: If my thread group name is LoginThreadgroup I need to create an Aggregate report file, View Result Tree file name with LoginThreadgroup.jtl LoginThreadgroup_VRT.jtl

I tried to use -${__BeanShell(ctx.getThreadGroup().getName())}.jtl
and 
${__threadGroupName}_ViewResultsTree_Failure_report.jtl

ETC but both dint work out well in my case.

I have many thread groups under test tree, for each, I would like to create `jtl` files with the respective thread group name.
Can anyone help me in this

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use [JMeter Functions and/or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) in "Filename" field of a [Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html)

In general using Listeners is not the best idea as they don't add any value and simply consume CPU, RAM and Disk resources.

I would rather suggest

1. Adding [__threadGroupName()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadGroupName) function as a prefix/postfix to your Samplers labels
2. If you want separate results for different Thread Groups you can use [Filter Results Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/) to extract Thread-Group-specific entries from the [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JtlFiles)
3. Aggregate Report can be generated using [JMeterPluginsCMD Command Line Tool](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeterpluginscmd-command-line/)

Comment: Im not allowed to change the sampler names as i need to compare with the previous test results using the overal aggregate reports

Comment: Thanks for your response Dmitri :)